# Assign name to root project while keeping the default aggregation

Tags: sbt

I have a fairly large *sbt* project (about 30 sub-projects).  From what I've figured out, sbt will use the name of the root directory as the name of the root project, if none is declared explicitly in `build.sbt`. Depending on where the project is checked out, e.g. in a CI environment, that name may change. I'm currently using sbt 1.2.8.

My issue is that I would like to assign a stable name to the root project so that I can e.g. run all tests using `sbt root/test` [0], leveraging the default aggregation of the root project over all sub-projects. The only way I have found so far to assign a name to the root project is by explicitly declaring the project. But this will disable the default aggregation.

Is there a way to assign a name to the root project that will keep the default aggregation over all sub-projects? Or is there another way to access the root project on the command line without relying on it's name?

[0]: The default project is changed by the `build.sbt` using `onLoad in Global := (Command.process("project ...", _)) compose (onLoad in Global).value`. So just running `sbt test` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potential solution without having to explicitly refer to the root project.

Given the following project structure consisting of root project, and sub-projects `core` and `util`

```
build.sbt 
core      
project   
src       
target    
util
```

and the following build definition in `build.sbt`

```
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
onLoad in Global := { Command.process("project util", _: State) } compose (onLoad in Global).value
ThisBuild / libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
```

we could run tests from all projects whilst being in any particular sub-project by defining a custom task `testAll` which evaluates `test` using [`inAnyProject`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/cbfcedc9d6d4b2d75b9420684c75585197eaa73b/main/src/main/scala/sbt/ScopeFilter.scala#L108) scope filter

```
val testAll = taskKey[Unit]("Run tests in all projects whilst being in any particular sub-project")
ThisBuild / testAll := Def.taskDyn {
  (Test / test).all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject))
}.value
```

Now executing `sbt` will load `util` sub-project by default, nevertheless `testAll` should run all tests from all projects:

```
sbt:util> testAll
[info] RootSpec:
[info] The Root object
[info] - should say root hello
[info] UtilSpec:
[info] The Util object
[info] - should say util hello
[info] CoreSpec:
[info] The Core object
[info] - should say core hello
[info] Run completed in 349 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Run completed in 309 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Run completed in 403 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 11-Apr-2019 16:29:26
sbt:util>
```

where `RootSpec`, `CoreSpec`, and `UtilsSpec` are at

```
src/test/scala/example/RootSpec.scala
core/src/test/scala/example/CoreSpec.scala
util/src/test/scala/example/UtilSpec.scala
```